# Facebook Graph API conversation reply limit lifted?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I developed while back a facebook graph api app that used the conversations edge to read messages and then reply back, this was done using the v2.3 version of the API.

Back then the API at

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/conversation/messages#publish

stated that:

> Note that a page can only reply to a user's message. It cannot
>   initiate a private message with a user. Also, a page can respond not
>   more than twice to a user's message before the user has replied back

But now i have to upgrade to v2.4 and i can't seem to find anywhere the above statement.

Does anyone now if this limit has been lifted?

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/conversation/messages/

> Pages can only reply to a message - they cannot initiate a conversation.

It´s right there, not all of it though. Just try to post more than 2 reply messages. I don´t think it has been lifted though, there is nothing about it in the changelog.

Comment: Yea, that's why i was wondering if the twice per user's message limit was lifted. You could always respond more than that but the fear of being flagged as spammer stopped me from using it in production. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @xyfantis Did you ever find out whether this limit had been lifted? All mention of it has been removed from the documentation, but I want to be sure.

Comment: why not just try it? should be easy to try in the api explorer, for example

Comment: @BetjaminRichards i can confirm that all mentions of it have been removed from the documentation, but i cannot confirm that this limit has been lifted. :(